# Insert and activate control button using keyboard shortcuts

Tags: microsoft-excel, keyboard-shortcuts

In Excel 2016, is there any way to insert a control, from the developer tab, using the keyboard? I have tried using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> and then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> (as you would do with a shape) but the controls will not insert.

Additionally, when a button has been inserted, is there any way to fire the macro attached to said button, using the keyboard? When I select the button using the selection pane, there does not seem to be any way of doing so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In Excel 2016, is there any way to insert a control, from the developer tab, using the keyboard?

If you mean **only** using the keyboard, then no. Keyboard <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>, <kbd>I</kbd>, <kbd>B</kbd> can get you to crosshair cursor and then you need a mouse click to place the control (in this case: button).

> When a button has been inserted, is there any way to fire the macro attached to said button, using the keyboard?

**Record...** button in **Assign Macro** dialog leads to **Record Macro** window where you can attach keyboard shortcut to the macro. This way, the shortcut won't be attached to the button, but the keyboard shortcut will be running your macro directly. In most cases it is practically the same thing.